# Angular 4: how to display UTC date in same timezone for every browser everywhere

Tags: angular, date, datetime, momentjs

I have such kind of date format:

`2017-09-17T09:00:00Z`

and i format it so: `{{date | date:'shortTime'}}`

but! in chrome everything is fine, but in safari: i get another timezone.

is it possible to show the same 9:00AM  in every browser every where in out world, so in any timezone i will see 9:00AM

is it possible to do?

https://plnkr.co/edit/tZ0s3XQSi0apjdceSddS?p=preview

ps: in angularJS we have an option `timezone` in datetime filter. But in angular 2+ - no.

Comment: You need to write custom pipe for using your timezone.

Comment: Take a look at [`amUtc`](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment#amutc-pipe) pipe of the [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) project. Probably you can use something like: `{{date | amUtc | amDateFormat: 'h:mm A' }}`

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121643/how-can-i-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-with-the-angular-4-date-pipe