# Format datetime get from db in Angular

Tags: angular, datetime

I have datetime data get from my db, raw data datetime is `2019-04-02T17:14:54.204515Z`
In view Component, I using `{{acc.updated_at|date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}` but my result I received is `03/04/2019 00:14:54`. Correct result is 02/04/2019 17:14:54
May I have wrong in my code? Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date as dd/MM/yyyy using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes)

Comment: sorry, I already updated my solution! I saw it but not work to me

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by:

```
 <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Test format Date Angular</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Format</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Model Date ({{dateNow}})</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let format of formatsDateTest">
          <td>{{dateNow | date: format}}</td>
          <td>{{format}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Model string ISO ({{dateNowISO}})</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let format of formatsDateTest">
          <td>{{dateNowISO | date: format}}</td>
          <td>{{format}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Model Number Milliseconds ({{dateNowMilliseconds}})</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let format of formatsDateTest">
          <td>{{dateNowMilliseconds | date: format}}</td>
          <td>{{format}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

and in .ts

```
 formatsDateTest: string[] = [
    'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
    'dd-MM-yyyy',
    'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    'MM/dd/yyyy',
    'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
    'yyyy/MM/dd',
    'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss',
    'dd/MM/yy',
    'dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss',
    ];

  dateNow : Date = new Date();
  dateNowISO = this.dateNow.toISOString();
  dateNowMilliseconds = this.dateNow.getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can format date by using `date` filer in html like this

First solution

```
 <span>{{created |date:'dd.MM.yyyy, hh:mm'}}</span>
```

Or you can format it in ts file

Second solution

```
toDate = new Date();
let toDate=(this.toDate.getDate()+1)+"/"+this.toDate.getMonth()+"/"+this.toDate.getFullYear();
```

by use Date object function (get Month ... etc)

`Update`

Your issue is from zone and you should display hour in 24 not 12 system 
plz see here you can find the solution 
[How can I deal with the timezone issue with the Angular 4 date pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121643/how-can-i-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-with-the-angular-4-date-pipe)

Comment: Colud you add ts code or What the type of acc.updated_at ? Is it Date Object? @Virtus

Comment: My purpose is to convert the Date data I received from the database to the dd.mm.yyy format, I tried all, but I received wrong date time. I think need to config time zone, but I don't know how to config

Comment: two results differ 7 hours

Comment: yeah I see, pls have a look on updated answer, I've put a link to fix zone issue