# Converting from 2019-08-08T20:41:00-1000 to Aug 08, 2019, 08:41 PM HST

Tags: angular, typescript, date, moment-timezone

I want to convert **2019-08-08T20:41:00-1000** to **MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a z**(Aug 08, 2019, 08:41 PM HST) format. I did not find any solution for this.. please help me out

I tried to get offset from that date and converting to date object but it is always showing aug 09, 2019, 12:32 PM GMT+5. which is wrong output...

expected Output is  **Aug 08, 2019, 08:41 PM HST**

Comment: Share your attempt...

Comment: ++ I think this should do the trick `{{your_date | date: 'MMM dd, y, hh:mm a z'}}`

Comment: @NicholasK it is showing  Aug 09, 2019, 12:11 PM GMT+5 instead of expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular's date pipe.

{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link [How can I deal with the timezone issue with the Angular 4 date pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121643/how-can-i-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-with-the-angular-4-date-pipe)  it solves my issue {{ competition.compStart | date: 'short' : **'-120'**}}