# Angular date pipe takes into account timezone

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I'm using a date pipe to display a time that I obtain from a webservice API. The date comes in the form `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z` an example of which would be `2020-08-12T07:06:07.000Z`.

However when I use the angular date pipe `{{ arr.time | date:'mediumTime' }}`, the time displayed is three hours more than the given time, here for example, the time displayed is `10:06:07`. I suspect this is because the browser takes into account my timezone, GMT+3. How do I display the exact time, without taking the timezone into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two conditions:

1. The date value which you are getting is UTC
2. Other than UTC

The last char of that must contain 'Z' if it is UTC.
So for non UTC we can add 'Z' before passing it to pipe

This will always print whatever value for date is received

```
{{arr.time?.charAt(arr.time?.length - 1) === 'Z' ? (arr.time | date:'mediumTime':'UTC') : (arr.time?.concat('Z') | date:'mediumTime':'UTC')}}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the date I receive ```2020-08-12T07:06:07.000Z``` already has a 'z' at the end of it, so it is taking the time as UTC, and is incrementing 3hrs to the display value. How do I make it show the raw value then?

Comment: Try the above mentioned code, it will print the exact time value that you recieve

Answer (score 2):

Timezone can be explicitly mentioned in angular date pipe.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

Or You can specify it in minutes for example for GMT-2, timezone: '-120'

```
{{ yourDate | date: 'mediumTime' : '-120'}}
```

Or Please refer this answer, it may help you out :-

[How can I deal with the timezone issue with the Angular 4 date pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121643/how-can-i-deal-with-the-timezone-issue-with-the-angular-4-date-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding timezone in pipe,

Specify it in minutes for example...For GMT+3, Timezone: '180'

```
{{ arr.time | date:'mediumTime' : '180'}}
```

Comment: Oh it's actually made it worse, added now hour more, showing ```11:06:07 AM```, instead of ```7:06:07 AM```, for timezone: '180'.

Comment: subtract/add the appropriate minutes accordingly. I suppose you have an idea now