# Why angular date pipe will minus one day?

Tags: angular, date, pipe

If I use `{{"2021-09-30T00:00:00Z" | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}`, it will automatically minus one day and show `2021-09-29`. I think it is because the time is 00:00, which make it confused?

How I can make the date correct as showing `2021-09-30` using date pipe in angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You added a Z at the end, which means it's interpreted as in the UTC (GMT) timezone.

If you're in a GMT-XX timezone, that's the previous day.

Try dropping the Z to have a timestamp at midnight in your local time zone.

Or alternatively, use UTC in your date formatter:

```
{{"2021-09-30T00:00:00Z" | date: "yyyy-MM-dd":"UTC"}}
```

Comment: The date is fixed and I cannot modify

Comment: Added alternative