# Angular datepipe convert date to GMT format

Tags: angular

In my Angular application I am trying to use Datepipe to convert date into GMT format and display.
I see in a [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121643/angular-4-date-pipe-displays-wrong-date-because-of-time-zones-how-to-fix-this) that Datepipe uses systems locale to convert the date.
How can I convert into GMT.

Assuming the date is 6/19/2023 12:00:00 AM, I want to dislay XXXXX (gmt-5)
I tried following code snippet which is not working.

```
new Date(datePipe.transform(new Date(6/19/2023 12:00:00 AM, 'MM/DD/YY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting to GMT-5, you can use `transform` as this code

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
    const date = new Date('6/19/2023 12:00:00 AM');
    this.formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'short', '-0500');
    console.log(this.formattedDate); // Display the formatted date
}
```

Demo code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hnkmjs

Comment: thank you. If we want to convert into like below is it possible.                            6/19/2023 at 12:00PM (GMT-5)